# How do I detect when a button is selected in npyscreen?

Tags: python, button, npyscreen

Right now, I am trying to make stylophone application in Python using npyscreen. What I'm trying to achieve, is to detect whenever a button is selected but not pressed. If you don't quite understand my goal, maybe this *example* will describe it more.

```
class Button(npyscreen.ButtonPress):
    def whenPressed(self):
        #Some code...
    
    def whenSelected(self): #Thats exactly what I am trying to do
        #Some other code...
```

I tried searching for a similar/same problem, but I didn't find anything, that would help me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

npyscreen does not offer this functionality natively (basis of what I know).
If you want to keep npyscreen as your TUI library, you have to developp your own using Curses.
Otherwise, and considering the way you try to structure your code, you should give a try to [PyCUI](https://jwlodek.github.io/py_cui-docs/DocstringGenerated/PyCui/).